# Copying and pasting from one workbook to another doesn't work

Tags: excel, vba, copy, range

I'm trying to do a simple thing. The code is supposed to copy specific ranges from one workbook to another but when I run the following code copying doesn't occur - nothing happens. (copying happens in the last part of Sub). I suspect it might be a problem with worksheets/workbooks but I'm really new into VBA so it's hard to say for me...

```
Function getHeaderRange(searched As String, ws As Worksheet) As Range
    Dim colNum
    Dim cellLength
    colNum = WorksheetFunction.Match(searched, ws.Range("5:5"))
    cellLength = ws.Range(ws.Cells(5, colNum), ws.Cells(5, colNum)).MergeArea.Count
    Set getHeaderRange = Range(ws.Cells(6, colNum), ws.Cells(6, colNum + cellLength - 1))
End Function

Function getDataRange(searched As String, hRange As Range) As Range
    Dim column: column = WorksheetFunction.Match(searched, hRange) + hRange.column - 1
    Set getDataRange = Range(Cells(6, column), Cells(6, column))
    Debug.Print (hRange.Worksheet.Parent.Name & "Sheet: " & hRange.Worksheet.Name)
    Set getDataRange = getDataRange.Offset(1, 0)
    Set getDataRange = getDataRange.Resize(8)
    
End Function

Sub main()
    Dim srcWs As Worksheet: Set srcWs = Workbooks("Period end open receivables, step 5").Sheets(1)
    Dim trgWs As Worksheet: Set trgWs = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Obiee")
    
    Dim searched As String
    Dim hSearched As String
    searched = "Magazines, Merchants & Office"
    
    Dim srcRange As Range: Set srcRange = getHeaderRange(searched, srcWs)
    Dim trgRange As Range: Set trgRange = getHeaderRange(searched, trgWs)
    
    Dim cocd() As Variant
    Dim i As Integer
    cocd = getHeaderRange("Magazines, Merchants & Office", trgWs)
    For i = 1 To UBound(cocd, 2)
        hSearched = cocd(1, i)
        getDataRange(hSearched, srcRange).Copy
        getDataRange(hSearched, trgRange).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    Next i
End Sub
```

When I change last lines to:

```
    For i = 1 To UBound(cocd, 2)
        hSearched = cocd(1, i)
        srcWs.Activate
        getDataRange(hSearched, srcRange).Copy
        trgWs.Activate
        getDataRange(hSearched, trgRange).Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
    Next i
```

It works just fine but I really would like to avoid this approach and find out what's wrong with the first one. Help really appreciated!

Edit: I'm including a to screenshots of workbooks (1. srcWb, 2. trgWb)
[image: Source Workbook]

[image: Target Workbook]

The file is huge and differentiated but in this cut they are the tables are the same.

Answer (score 0):

**Your ranges aren't fully qualified..**

When they're not qualified, Excel will guess which worksheet the range in question resides on, usually using the currently active worksheet. That's why your workaround works as you change the active worksheet.

---

This line needs to be fully qualified:

```
cellLength = Range(ws.Cells(5, colNum), ws.Cells(5, colNum)).MergeArea.Count
```

So it'll become:

```
Function getHeaderRange(searched As String, ws As Worksheet) As Range
    Dim colNum
    Dim cellLength
    colNum = WorksheetFunction.Match(searched, ws.Range("5:5"))
    cellLength = ws.Range(ws.Cells(5, colNum), ws.Cells(5, colNum)).MergeArea.Count
    Set getHeaderRange = ws.Range(ws.Cells(6, colNum), ws.Cells(6, colNum + cellLength - 1))
End Function
```

---

Also, this line is not qualified at all:

```
Set getDataRange = Range(Cells(6, column), Cells(6, column))
```

So it'll become:

```
Function getDataRange(searched As String, hRange As Range) As Range
    Dim column: column = WorksheetFunction.Match(searched, hRange) + hRange.column - 1
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = hRange.Worksheet
    Set getDataRange = ws.Range(ws.Cells(6, column), ws.Cells(6, column))
    Debug.Print (ws.Parent.Name & "Sheet: " & ws.Name)
    Set getDataRange = getDataRange.Offset(1, 0)
    Set getDataRange = getDataRange.Resize(8)
End Function
```

---

As per my comment below, to radically speed things up, I'd recommend removing these two lines from `Main()`:

```
getDataRange(hSearched, srcRange).Copy
getDataRange(hSearched, trgRange).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

and replacing them with:

```
getDataRange(hSearched, trgRange).Value = getDataRange(hSearched, srcRange).Value
```

Comment: Thank you! Your explanation cleared it out for me and I realized a few things thanks to you but what's really weird - it's still not working, it's acting the same way... And now when it's all qualified I don't see reason behind this.

Comment: Can you share a small example dataset (source) - just the minimum to get this working - in your question?

Comment: I mocked up your source table (and destination empty table) here and your `Main()` with my subroutines **works** and copies the data correctly on my machine. I did find it a bit slow though, so I'd suggest changing the method of copying to .value=.value which I'll add to my answer.